# Image colors changed after saving with PIL

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, rgb

I tried to create very simple image consisting of two columns - one green and the other one in red, but when I run script that is shown below I got an image in other colors.
Any idea why it happens?

```
from PIL import Image

list=[(0,255,00),(255,0,0),(0,255,00),(255,0,0),(0,255,00),(255,0,0)]
a=Image.new('RGB',(2,3), "white")
a.putdata(list)
a.save('my_picture.jpg')
```

The image I've got:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esL85.jpg)

Comment: As an aside, don't name variables the same as predefined python variables (e.g. `list` in this example).

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're saving your image as JPEG, which by default is going to have various options enabled that will alter the colors of your image (since JPEG is a lossy image type), especially [Chroma Subsampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_subsampling), which will alter the 'perceived' colors of your images. Since you're making such a tiny image, this effect will be quite dramatic and results in the colors you're seeing, and by default `libjpeg` is probably using `4:2:2` subsampling (rather than `4:4:4`).

A couple things you can do:

1. Save as a PNG

   If you're dealing with computer graphic-y images (like what you're doing right now) and not photo-level stuff, save your image as a PNG which is lossless.

   ```
   from PIL import Image

   pixels = [(0,255,00),(255,0,0),(0,255,00),(255,0,0),(0,255,00),(255,0,0)]
   a=Image.new('RGB',(2,3), "white")
   a.putdata(pixels)
   a.save('my_picture.png')
   ```

   And your resultant image will look like this

   [image: Sample PNG]
2. Specify JPEG `subsampling=0` or `subsampling="4:4:4"`

   You can pick `4:4:4` subsampling with `subsampling=0`, and get the highest level of subsampling to preserve your intended colors as much as possible.

   ```
   a.save("my_picture.jpg", quality=95, subsampling=0)
   ```

   And your resultant JPEG will look probably as you intended:

   [image]

---

You can see more options for how you can deal with [image formats](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html), and here are the options for what you can specify to `subsampling`:

```
subsampling

    If present, sets the subsampling for the encoder.

        keep: Only valid for JPEG files, will retain the original image setting.

        4:4:4, 4:2:2, 4:2:0: Specific sampling values

        0: equivalent to 4:4:4

        1: equivalent to 4:2:2

        2: equivalent to 4:2:0

    If absent, the setting will be determined by libjpeg or libjpeg-turbo.
```